# PHP base64_decode! "@" comes out as a "¡"

Tags: php, encoding, gmail, mb-convert-encoding

I am pulling some code from an email (google) and it translates the code or encrypts it when I use an @ symbol it changes to and upside down explanation point.¡ I use the code below and  it fixes it back to the @ symbol but it adds a "?" and the end or a "n". It also changes the $ to a funky symbol. Any ideas how to decode this properly? Again its a Google encryption. Don't know if that helps...

```
$Body = base64_decode($Body);
$Body = mb_convert_encoding($Body, "utf-8");
$Body = htmlspecialchars($Body);
$Body = preg_replace('/¡/',"@",$Body);
```

Comment: What happens if you simply `base64_decode` it and output the value (no `mb_convert_encoding`, `htmlspecialchars` or `preg_replace`)?

Comment: I just tried that. Didn't work. I put in... "PDF @@@" and it came out as...  Pdf ¡¡¡
n

Comment: How are you looking at the result? What encoding is the original in? It's an email? Look at its headers what encoding it's supposed to be.

Comment: Are you sure the input is base64-encoded? Could you quote a part of it and the MIME headers from the mail?

Comment: Backtracking blind through Character Encoding lists is very time consuming. We need to know the character encoding from the email, however I feel you'll probably answer you're own question when you do find it.

Comment: Here is the header section your asking for
-----------------------------------------------
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UGRmIKGhoQ0KDQotLQ0KU2VudCB1c2luZyBTTVMtdG8tZW1haWwuICBSZXBseSB0byB0aGlzIGVt
YWlsIHRvIHRleHQgdGhlIHNlbmRlciBiYWNrIGFuZCAgDQpzYXZlIG9uIFNNUyBmZWVzLg0KaHR0
cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS92b2ljZQ0K
----------------------------------------
This last part is the message I think. It comes out like this below... 
-----------------

Comment: ----------------------
Pdf ¡¡¡
----------------------
Then I use $Body = preg_replace('/¡/',"@",$Body);
to change it to PDF @@@ but I still get funny characters in the end. You guys are great. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: INTERESTING NOTE: When I decode it before entering a MySQL database it gets those funky chars. If I use... $Body = preg_replace('/¡/',"@",$Body); after I pull from the database it works fine. I of course use the code below before I put it in a database--------------------$Body = base64_decode($Body);
$Body = mb_convert_encoding($Body, "utf-8");

Comment: Reposted as [Google encoding issue base64 and PHP decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379252/google-encoding-issue-base64-and-php-decode)

Answer (score 1):

I use this for fetching my email body from gmail.

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $mail, 1);
$body = quoted_printable_decode($body);
$body = urldecode($body);
```

And it's work well

Comment: That won't work correctly for all messages; you have to look at the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header of the message to know what to do to it.